# react-spring and typescript not callable error

Tags: react-spring

I am unable to make the simplest example of react-spring work:

```
import { useSpring } from 'react-spring/three'

export const myComponent = () => {
    const [spring, setSpring] = useSpring(() => ({ xpos: 0 }))
    setSpring({xpos: 10})

    return (
        <Canvas />
    )
}
```

It gives me this:

> Uncaught TypeError: setSpring is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more discussion on this here: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1359

Current work-around: use `setSpring.current[0].start()` rather than `setSpring()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works with react-spring v9.0.0 beta.

Comment: This isn't true - I'm using the react-spring v9.0.0 beta and running into the exact same problem.